# Configure log4j to Auto create application log files when deleted

Tags: java, log4j

How to configure log4j to Auto
create application log files when
deleted manually without restarting
the server?
Currently we have to restart the
server if someone deletes the log
files.We are using websphere
application server.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106258/log4j-fileappender-recreating-deleted-files

Comment: Thanks Anil.  Actually I was looking for log4j level configuration instead of writing some implementation as suggested in the post link shared by you but I think this the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using log4j in web application, so maybe the method below may be helpful:

write a jsp file to reconfigure the log4j. put it in webapp floder. just like this:

reset.jsp

```
<%
    java.util.Properties pro = new java.util.Properties();
    pro.put("log4j.appender.A1.Threshold","INFO");
    pro.put("log4j.appender.A1","org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender");
    pro.put("log4j.appender.A1.File","/var/log/h3cloud.log");
    pro.put("log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize","100000KB");
    pro.put("log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex","5");
```

/* all the log4j.properties content..  */

```
    org.apache.log4j.LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(pro);
%>
```

After I deleted the "/var/log/tomcat6/h3cloud.log", I open http://***/reset.jsp, the new "/var/log/h3coud.log" is recreated.